# Conflicto entre urls por el slug

Tags: php, laravel, slug

se me esta produciendo conflicto al usar slug cuando quiero editar mis registros, por ejemplo,que pasaría si tengo 2 registros con un mismo slug,me daría conflicto ya que son iguales, como puedo evitar esto? , tendría que concatenar su "id" por ejemplo en ese slug, para hacerlo "valores unicos" y que no hayan conflictos entre si?,o hay una solución más limpia? :

url registro 1: http://secretaria/daem/et-rerum-earum-labore-voluptate-alias-sunt/editar
url registro 2 : http://secretaria/daem/et-rerum-earum-labore-voluptate-alias-sunt/editar

Me toma el primero e ignora el segundo siempre,conflicto

```php
  GET|HEAD        daem/{registro}/editar .................................................................................................... daem.edit › DaemRegistros@edit
```

El valor registro lo cambio por el slug

Comment: los slugs deberían ser únicos, o al menos tener una url única tipo `/unacosa/un-slug` y `/otracosa/un-slug` si es por cuestiones de SEO fijate cual es la razón de que haya 2 contenidos iguales en (potencialmente) 2 url distintas. varios frameworks lo resuelven chequeando al guardar el slug si este ya no existe y si existe le agregan un número ( no necesariamente el id ) que se va incrementando en un do/while hasta que se encuentra uno que no colisione lo que te deja cosas tipo `/daem/un-slug` `/daem/un-slug-2` `/daem/un-slug-3` etc...

Comment: @aloMalbarez Hola Alo! Gracias por comentar, y si, también estaba pensando que los slugs deberian ser unicos, cuando me refiero a concatenar el id es como el ejemplo que hiciste abajo,al final poner el id,de esa forma no habria conflicto ya que los id son unicos.. Me podrías mencionar algún paquete que me ayudaría con este checkeo?

Comment: sin code es complicado, pero ya que estas en laravel fijate https://packagist.org/?q=sluggable hay varias opciones con diferentes requerimientos

Comment: @aloMalbarez Gracias por comentar!, Ya lo solucione!, Use el Paquete cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable , y pude solucionar mi problema super facil,gracias!